# Blazor login page not working all the time

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a simple admin panel to access a administration page. i type /admin on my url and get this page.

```
    <form>
    <center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="password" id="username" @bind-value="adminusername" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Password:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" @bind-value="adminpassword" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <button @onclick="@authenticatecredentials" id="login" style="background-color:green;" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Login</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </center>
</form>

@code {
    public string adminusername { get; set; }
    public string adminpassword { get; set; }



    public void authenticatecredentials()
    {
        if (adminusername == "myusername" && adminpassword == "mypassword")
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Ka9fVDrE7vc", true);
        }
        else
        {
            jSruntime.InvokeVoidAsync("invalidcredentials");
        }
    }
}
```

invalidcredentials is an javascript alert:

```
function invalidcredentials() {
alert("Invalid Credentials");
}
```

When i run the application, sometimes it logs in successfully sometimes it does not. When it doesn't, i get a (?) next to my url on my Admin login page:

[image]

I need a simple hardcoded "login" page that will direct to the admin panel link. No SQL or Models.

Comment: Ignoring for the moment how insecure this solution is, have you tried passing `false` in the call to `NavigateTo`? And, shouldn't you `await` the js interop call?

Comment: Security is not an issue since this app will run internally. This is build just for the sake of procedure. This is my first web app thus i am not sure how to implement what you have mentioned, Thanks for your help

Comment: Simplest solution is to remove the `form` wrapper and it will work because it will stop submitting the page back to the server and run as a SPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is doing a `submit` which reloads the page instead of using Blazor's router. Prevent this by adding `@onclick:preventDefault` (or use [EditForm instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editform?view=aspnetcore-6.0)):

```
<button @onclick="@authenticatecredentials" @onclick:preventDefault id="login" style="background-color:green;" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Login</button>
```

Then, change your call to `NavigateTo`. By passing `true` as the second parameter you are again bypassing Blazor router. You can pass `false` or omit the argument:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Ka9fVDrE7vc");
```

> A note on security:

I don't know if your app is wasm or server, but either way it is not secure, even for internal use only. there is a reason you are putting a "login" page so making it so easy to bypass could come back to bite you.

If this is a wasm app then the problem is even worse. Anyone can download the application dll from the browser tools and decompile it, seeing the username and password, or just seeing the obfuscated url which can be accessed without login:

[image]

Comment: Or `type="button"` instead of `@onclick:preventDefault`.

Comment: @Crowcoder its a Server app, Security does not really matter since no user has the knowledge or a reason to do what you have described above, but i definitely see what you are saying. is there any simple way to make more secure?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a simple way. But most straightforward might be to integrate [Microsoft Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server)

Answer (score 1):

The button inside the form, has the default value of the attribute `type=submit`, if not specified. To fix this, set the type to **button**:

```
...
<button type='button'.../>
...
```

Comment: This "works", but it reloads the page instead of routing to it if you don't also change the call to `NavigateTo`